# Populate ArrayCollection with HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, httpservice, arraycollection

Yes there is a question like this one, but there is no activity and no answer.

I want to load data from a external XML file, using a HTTPService, and on the ResultEvent of the same HTTPService i want him to populate a ArrayCollection with the data from the XML.

I think a ArrayCollection is the ideal for this XML. but I'm open to suggestions.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PhotoGalleryData>
    <Photo>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Summer Vacation</name>
        <description>In vacation</description>
        <source>vacation.JPG</source>
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Winter Vacation</name>
        <description>coold</description>
        <source>vacation2.JPG</source>
    </Photo>
</PhotoGalleryData>
```

I thought that this simple line in `getDataResultHandler()`, would be enough to populate the ArrayCollection.

```
<mx:HTTPService id="getData"
        url="{XMLDataFileLocation}"
        fault="getDataFaultHandler()"
        result="getDataResultHandler()"/>

[Bindable]
private var PhotoData:ArrayCollection;

private function getDataResultHandler():void
{
    PhotoData = new ArrayCollection(getData.lastResult.PhotoGalleryData.photo)
}
```

But i guess it isn't, because just to be sure i have placed a List binded to the ArrayCollection to actually see if it really was populated.

```
<mx:List dataProvider="{PhotoData}" labelField="name"/>
```

And the list didn't showed any data, so isn't working as supposed to be.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

> **NOTE**
>
> The `<mx:List/>` used is just to be
>   sure that the ArrayCollection is
>   indeed populated, it won't be used in
>   the App.

---

**Results taking Bozho advice.**

With Bozho changes Flex doesn't report the var type error any more, but once i run it. Adobe flash does report this.

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion
>   failed: cannot convert
>   mx.utils::ObjectProxy@22cd311 to
>   mx.collections.ArrayCollection.   at
>   PhotoGallery/getDataResultHandler()[C:\Users\Fábio
>   Antunes\Documents\Flex Builder 3\Photo
>   Gallery\src\ActionScripts\PhotoGallery.as:56]
>     at
>   PhotoGallery/__getData_result()[C:\Users\Fábio
>   Antunes\Documents\Flex Builder 3\Photo
>   Gallery\src\PhotoGallery.mxml:23]     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>     at
>   mx.rpc.http.mxml::HTTPService/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\http\mxml\HTTPService.as:290]
>     at
>   mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:193]
>     at
>   mx.rpc::Responder/result()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:43]
>     at
>   mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:74]
>     at
>   DirectHTTPMessageResponder/completeHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\DirectHTTPChannel.as:403]
>     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()

Well and the line 23 that Flash reports the error its:

```
PhotoData = ArrayCollection(event.result);
```

Line 23 is:

```
result="getDataResultHandler(event)"
```

Comment: Why does it need to be an `ArrayCollection`?  You can use an `XMLListCollection` as a data provider in place of an `ArrayCollection` in most cases.

Comment: Ryan, taking your suggestion how do i can populate the XMLListCollection with the HTTPService data?

Comment: added an answer with a link to a tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use an `XMLListCollection` in place of an `ArrayCollection` the process of converting the result object is more straightforward. [Here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/29/dynamically-loading-xml-files-using-the-httpservice-tag/) is a good tutorial explaining how to go about this.

EDIT:

The key things to get from this tutorial are this:

- you need to set the result format of the service to `e4x`.
- you need to cast the result object as `XML` object, extract the repeating nodes as an `XMLList`, and construct an `XMLListCollection` from the list like so:

  ```
  private function httpService_result(evt:ResultEvent):void 
  {
       var xmlList:XMLList = XML(evt.result).path.to.repeating.element;
       xmlListColl = new XMLListCollection(xmlList);
  }
  ```

Comment: I was trying a similar approach with the ArrayCollection. I will try with a XMLListCollection...

Comment: They are interchangeable in most cases, with the `ArrayCollection` taking an `Array` as an argument, and the `XMLListCollection` taking an `XMLList`. I can't think of a general reason why you would want to mix the two together.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your script like this:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="getData" url="{XMLDataFileLocation}"/>
<mx:List dataProvider="{getData.lastResult.Photo}" labelField="name"/>
```

The `lastResult` of your `getData` will be the root of your XML. By retrieving `lastResult.Photo` you'll get an `XMLList` of the photos.

Comment: Yes i know that thanks, but the thing is that i use the list just to be sure that it was working, the list won't be used in the App.